# How to deploy a program with a separate server and client code?

Tags: javascript, heroku

I recognize this question is ridiculously stupid but I need an answer to this. I have tried going through google for an answer to this, but no luck so far.

So, I am going to build an application in JavaScript (using React and Redux) with separate client and server logic. The code for each will be housed in separate files. If I deploy both my server and client code logic to heroku, how will it be deployed by heroku?

By my understanding, heroku deploys a single app, and it will see this as essentially two different apps. Do I need to write both client and server logic together and push them up to Heroku necessarily?

Comment: Like this? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of what you are trying to do with your app it is quite hard to give a correct answer.

But if you want to use Heroku node.js you will be deploying both server and client logic in one project.

Here is an example for react.js: http://ditrospecta.com/javascript/react/es6/webpack/heroku/2015/08/08/deploying-react-webpack-heroku.html

Comment: So what I am doing is create a stock market app where people can add tickers and use WebSocket to push any state changes to all connected clients. 
What do you mean use Heroku node.js? You mean use the Heroku tool belt CLI?

Comment: No, i just ment a node.js project on heroku

Comment: Okay, so that is what I intend to do. I use node.js and redux store to build the backend server of the project, and use React, Redux and React Router to build the front end.